# Jenkins is not able to update GitHub branch status checks

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I am using Jenkins with the version **"2.263.1"** which is deployed on the EKS cluster. I have set up a webhook in Jenkins and added **"branch protection rule"** in the GitHub repo for PR and Branch status check.
The integration is working and able the get the updated status check in GitHub for each PR we raise.

Please find the below image for reference.
[image]

But intermittently, I am observing that for some of the PRs, the status checks are not getting updated in PR even though Jenkins job get successfully execute. For example,
[image]

When above issue occurs, according to my observation, sometimes status is not getting updated for **"continuous-integration/jenkins/branch"** and sometimes it is not getting updated for **"continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge"** status check.

I thought it might be the networking issue and tried using **paping** to send continuous requested to the GitHub API endpoint (). But even after keeping the request count to 10000, not a single request failed.

Any idea how to debug and hopefully fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We are also facing the same issue, Jenkins job status is not publishing on github PR's. This is an GitHub plugin issue, apparently someone else is also facing this issue and  issue has been raised here https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/816

Answer (score 0):

on 22 Apr Github reported Github API issue https://www.githubstatus.com/history.

In our case after this incident we stated getting `API rate limit exceeded` for our GitHub user and we suspect this was the reason due to which Jenkins was not able to publish the job status back to the GitHub.

Now it is working again without doing any changes from our end.